# <fieldset> keeps <select>s showing up vertically

Tags: jquery, html

I have this piece of html, JQuery is filling up my  boxes and I'm using fieldsets so I can grab only needed selection and POST it to my servlet.
Problem is it looks like this

[image]

It keeps getting drawn vertically and I would like them in one line. I think it's the fieldsets that cause it, but worst thing is I can't use a table to keep it in row because that breaks fieldsets.

Any solution to this or alternative? (e.g. helping me eliminate fieldsets and still be able to send only selected s ?)

```
<form name="forma" id="forma" method="post">
            <fieldset id="range">
                <fieldset id="currency">
                    <fieldset id="pricelist">
                        <select id="somesel" name="somesel" size=8>
                            <option value= >Waiting for a server response</option>
                        </select>
                    </fieldset>
                    <select id="somesel1" name="somesel1" size=8 disabled>
                        <option value= >Make selection in the parent list</option>
                    </select>
                </fieldset>
                <select id="somesel2" name="somesel2" size=8 disabled>
                    <option value= >Make selection in the parent list</option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>
        </form> 
        <button id="somebutton">press here</button>
            <input name="result" value="">
            <button id="anotherbutton">Another Button</button>
```

Comment: `fieldset` defaults to `display: block`; you'll need to change that.

Comment: (1) Fieldsets are block-level elements; either remove them or change their CSS to `display: inline-block`. (2) Fieldsets aren't really supposed to be nested like that, semantically speaking. It represents, as you might guess, a set of fields -- so it would make more sense to wrap all your `<select>` elements in a single fieldset.

Comment: changing that css attribute fixed it. but since you all say fieldsets shouldn't be nested, can you advise me how to fix my JQuery code to let it fetch the right data?
I basically would like to know what can I enter in the `data: $("#pricelist").serialize()` to send for example only first two fields?

Comment: Why send only two fields? I'd suggest sending everything, and let the backend ignore the ones that are empty. It's easier to ignore a value than try to configure your frontend to not pass it to your backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fieldset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/fieldset.html#fieldset-display)s default to `display: block`; you'll need to change to `inline-block`.